# Laravel 5: Login password doesn't match with saved one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

When I register a user, using Laravels built in controller Auth\RegisterController.php, everything works great and I'm immediately logged in.
The problem is when I logout and try to login via Auth\LoginController.php, It shows that the password is incorrect.
Code looks like this:

- RegisterController.php

  ```
  $user = $this->create([
      'name' => $request['name'],
      'email' => $request['email'],
      'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
  ]);
  ```
- LoginController.php

  ```
  if(!Auth::attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
      return back()->withErrors([
          'message' => 'Wrong Emial or Password!'
      ]);
  }
  ```

I've checked the database and everything seems ok.

What is also weird about this problem, is when I hash the password ( using `Hash::make('password')` ) with `php artisan tinker` and then replace it in the database for the same user, everything works...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't send a hashed password to the [`create()`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L64) function, the function takes care of that. The reason you can't login is because you hashed the password twice.

```
$user = $this->create([
    'name' => $request['name'],
    'email' => $request['email'],
    'password' => $request['password'],
]);
```